# Detecting is something being dragged over my application

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, state

I need to know is some object being dragged over my Delphi application.

For example: while the user dragging some item from ListView to ListBox, or dragging some file from Explorer into my LitsView, I want to check at any moment is he still dragging or not dragging anymore.

Can I find this without hooking drag events?

*Delphi XE*

Comment: What do you mean by "without hooking drag events"

Comment: Have you looked at Anders Melander's "Drag and Drop Component Suite"?  I've done very similar things with ease using that in both XE and XE2.  Here's the URL: http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I mean I can catch something like OnStartDrag and set boolean flag there but I want some more general solution

Comment: I don't see how your proposed solution lacks generality.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What about OLE dragging? I thought VCL has some special undocumented flags for this or I can ask Windows API is dragging happens right now.

Comment: I handle drag/drop from other apps by implementing IDropTarget. Again, set a flag when `DragEnter` is called, and reset it on `DragLeave` and `Drop`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Um, can you add this as answer?

Comment: @Andrew: there is no API to ask Windows if it is currently dragging something.  And Anders' components are based on OLE drag&drop (IDropTarget, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by making a note when the drag process starts, for example when `IDropTarget.DragEnter` is called. And then reset the flag when the `DragLeave` or `Drop` is subsequently called.